# remove item from navigationItem to display navigationItems title programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem

i have a UISegmentedControl in the Center of my NavigationItem. When a user with fewer rights logs into the app, the segmentedControl should be hidden, so instead of it the title of the navigationItem is shown.

I try to use .isHidden = true, but the title won't be shown.

What is a good way to achieve this? Of course, if you logout and login as an admin, you should see the segmentedControl again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the UISegmentedControl is set via navItem.titleView...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    title = "My Title"
    if userHasRights {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
        // Setup segmented control...
        navItem.titleView = segmentedControl
    }
}
```

Setting the .titleView on the navigation item should override the title set on the view controller.

Comment: I placed the segmentedControl via storyboard into the titleView. I simply dragged it farther on top, which made it possible to use with your solution thank you!